# Using qchecksum instead of boost crc16

Tags: c++, qt, boost, crc

I want to take crc16 on a packet using [qchecksum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#qChecksum) instead of [boost crc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/crc/crc.html) but I cannot take same results. how can I take crc16 checksum like boost crc in qt?

```
boost::crc<16, 0x1040, 0, 0, false, false>(packet, 4)
```

Comment: Can you show us the line where you tried to use `QChecksum`?

Comment: @Torbjörn, suppose packet is equal to "0x00000000" then boost crc is equal to zero but qt crc is equal to 64734

Comment: There isn't a single 16-bit CRC polynomial, and there isn't a single way to use one polynomial to compute a CRC either. Why do you assume that boost and Qt use the same polynomial, with the same parameters?

Answer (score 3):

There are many CRC-16 polynomials and parameter sets. qchecksum is just an implementation of one of them. So no, you can't make qchecksum match arbitrary boost checksum. But you can adjust boost checksum parameters to match qchecksum if this is an option.

Looking at qchecksum source (and playing with parameters) it seems to be this one:

```
boost::crc<16, 0x1021, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, true, true>
```